# How to improve performance on select * into #temp from huge_table

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, indexing

```
Select * into #temp from huge_table 
Where col1= @input1
And col2= @input2
And col3 = @input3
```

Huge_table has three indexes : one clustered and two non clustered. Clustered index seek is taking long to complete.

Comment: First question, do you need `SELECT *`? Second question, do you need all those rows? If the answer is "yes" to both, what else are you expecting when you want the instance to read every column, of every row? if not, then fix your query and only return the columns and rows you need; I'm sure itll be (significantly) faster.

Comment: If you are reading all the rows of a table indexes are of little consequence.

Comment: Is that really what your query?  No WHERE clause, no joins or views in your FROM clause and do you really need all of the source columns?  If so, then: 1) you're already using the fastest possible SQL command, the only way to make this faster would involve reconfiguring your databases file-disk configurations.  And, 2) Why do want to work on a complete copy of huge_table when the  original already has indexes?

Comment: You cannot readily improve the performance of a query that is copying an entire table into a new table. (You could put the new table on S-RAM or upgrade the server or something like that.)

Comment: Im filtering with where condition, I want the rows to a temp storage because it will be used frequently so I'm using this. Yes I agree and I will use only the column names that will be used.

Comment: @Charlieface No, let's not advocate for arbitrary hints without understanding why the query is slow and what options are available to improve it. Since we have no idea what "huge table" actually means, the entire premise might be moot based on the number of rows in the table and the number selected.

Comment: @SMor Good point

Comment: Are those "col1", "col2" and "col3" columns actually contained in the indexes? If not, then the index will not help. If they are contained there, the exact index configuration matters - so please add